# How can I swap out YouTube thumbnails for my latest upload?

Tags: html, css, youtube

I'm wanting to create a "Latest Video" block on my website, but I only need the YouTube thumbnail image and MAYBE the title of the video. I found a method for doing an embed for the latest video itself, but I'm uncertain if I can modify it for just the thumbnail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YouTube Recent Upload Thing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="static_video"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showVideo(response) {
            if(response.data && response.data.items) {
                var items = response.data.items;
                if(items.length>0) {
                    var item = items[0];
                    var videoid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
                    console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
                    var video = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"; 
                    $('#static_video').html(video);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/urusernamehere/uploads?max-results=1&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=showVideo"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can this be repurposed for my idea? And how can I do it if it can't? I have basic HTML and CSS knowledge, with a very limited understanding of javascript and php. If I can just get something that will swap the thumbnail and ideally display the title, I can handle styling and implementation. Also interested in the same for specific playlists' most recent addition, but that doesn't have to happen.

Comment: Maybe to clear this up a little, I'm looking for a way for my code to look at my channel, see what I recently uploaded, and swap the thumbnail for the video. I'm not sure how to use API, so I was hoping there's a simple HTML/CSS method, and if it needs a little PHP or Javascript I might be able to follow. >.< One of the many problems of being interested in coding but not very well practiced yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean but you can try something like:

```
    <div onclick="this.style.display='none'; this.nextSibling.style.display='block';"><img src="image.png" style="cursor:pointer" /></div><div style="display:none">
<!-- Embed code here -->
</div>
```

Comment: When you say Embed code, do you mean the script from above or the embed code from YouTube?